# ALSAMIXER cannot start - ALSA lib dlmisc.c:337:(snd_dlobj_cache_get0) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_ctl_pipewire.so

Tags: sound, alsa, jack, pipewire

Reverted to plain Jack2 and PulseAudio bridge after having SEVERE XRUNS problems with Pipewire compared to the legacy drivers ON THE SAME HARDWARE.

Suddenly yesterday the Focusrite Gen 1 18i20 that I had been using for 10 years flawlessly did not work anymore after an update (only) on Ubuntu 22.04.1.

This interface needs to toggle the USB SYNC to un-mute audio. Normally done with QASMIXER, but QASMixer now showed UI with different options and the SYNC toggling did not work.

Reverted to ALSAMIXER, but got this error: ALSA lib dlmisc.c:337:(snd_dlobj_cache_get0) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_ctl_pipewire.so

That was suspicious, because pipewire had never been installed.

Removed pipewire (sudo apt-get remove Pipewire). then the whole GNOME desktop disappeared after reboot. Reinstalled it with sudo apt-get install gnome. This was the 2nd time that happened after removing pipewire, so not an coincidence. Spend hours to reconfigure GNOME back to the preferred way.

After that QASmixer UI had the setting was before and USB SYNC worked fine.

The risk is that pipewire, even it is really great for aggregation of hardware, if not ready for prime-time and when there are issues, the PW folks point to Ubuntu and the other way around, leaving the users behind with non-functional hardware.

It may be better if Canonical refrains from Pipewire from default into the distribution before they have actually tested it EXTERNAL audio hardware and not only consumer grade on board audio.

A suggestion could be when PW is not installed, Ubuntu should not install it or give the user options to choose.

Any idea why this could be happening that Pipewire gets installed ?
How to get ALSAMIXER back to work ?

Comment: As mentioned above Ubuntu 22.04.1. Linux H3 5.15.0-56-lowlatency #62-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 23 09:50:07 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. As for the command, just tried it again copy/paste:  sudo apt-get remove pipewire
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apg caribou five-or-more folks-common fonts-cantarell four-in-a-row gir1.2-ac....

Answer (score 0):

sudo rm /etc/alsa/conf.d/99-pipewire-default.conf

This restored ALSAMIXER. The likely root cause is that Ubuntu is not removing pipewire dependencies correctly.

P.S apt-remove pipewire on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 removes a whole lot of packages.

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
apg caribou five-or-more folks-common fonts-cantarell four-in-a-row gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-champlain-0.12
gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-dazzle-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0
gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gfbgraph-0.2 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 gir1.2-grilo-0.3 gir1.2-gtkchamplain-0.12 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mediaart-2.0 gir1.2-mutter-10 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gkbd-capplet gnome-2048 gnome-backgrounds gnome-bluetooth-3-common gnome-chess gnome-clocks gnome-color-manager
gnome-contacts gnome-control-center-faces gnome-games gnome-klotski gnome-maps gnome-music gnome-nibbles gnome-online-accounts gnome-robots
gnome-system-monitor gnome-taquin gnome-tetravex gnome-user-share gnome-weather gvfs-fuse hitori hoichess iagno libapache2-mod-dnssd
libcaribou-common libcaribou0 libcolord-gtk1 libfolks-eds26 libfolks26 libfreerdp-server2-2 libgnome-bluetooth-3.0-13 libgnomekbd-common
libgnomekbd8 libgsound0 libgtop-2.0-11 libgtop2-common libmutter-10-0 libproxy1-plugin-webkit librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2
librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-gst-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libvncserver1 libxklavier16 lightsoff mobile-broadband-provider-info
network-manager-gnome pipewire-bin power-profiles-daemon python3-macaroonbakery python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons python3-rfc3339 python3-tz
quadrapassel rygel rygel-playbin rygel-tracker swell-foop switcheroo-control tali xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
chrome-gnome-shell gdm3 gnome gnome-control-center gnome-core gnome-remote-desktop gnome-session gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-prefs
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-shell-extensions gstreamer1.0-pipewire pipewire pipewire-media-session ubuntu-session
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 15 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Talking to the PW team long time ago, it seems there was potentially something incorrect with PW when removing it. We are a year later now so this might have been resolved.